# Error in passing arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import sys
import argparse
import ORFALGO as orf
#get filenames from command line arguments
firstSeq = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv)>=3:
    resultFile = sys.argv[2]
else:
    resultFile='ORF.txt'
def parse_fasta(fasta): 
        sequences=''
        sep=''
        with open(fasta) as f:
            next(f)
            for line in f:
                sequences += (line.strip())
        return sequences
seq= parse_fasta(firstSeq)
```

---

```
File "C:\Users\ram\Desktop\python\hw2\ass2\LongORF.py", line 6, in <module>
    firstSeq = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: And how are you calling your script?

Comment: Are you passing a file name to the script when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv[0]` is your script name, you should provide at least a parameter when invoking your script.
Currently `sys.argv` does not have a index=1 element thus error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it as

```
python LongORF.py firstSeq resultFile
```

Here

LongORF.py is `sys.argv[0]`
firstSeq is `sys.argv[1]`
resultFile is `sys.argv[2]`